# C# count if a imputfield letter is in a word

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

How can i count if a value, from a input box, is in an verb that's in a string?

And if possible, give the right position of the letter in the verb (like hangman)
Also, if a verb is not containing a letter, place that letter on a list.

**example with the word NAME:**

1. enter the letter E
2. letter is in word  -last position (4th)

**example HELP**

1. Enter the letter V letter is not inside the word Add the letter to a
   list (list with wrong letters)

Thanks for your help;)

Comment: please clarify by giving some examples

Comment: can you clarify with an example?

Comment: Roy it sounds like you are new to programming. Which is great, we all had to start and learn at some point. However, many of the questions you are asking leads me to believe that you have not done any research on your own. Provide us with some examples of what you have tried or ideas that have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would regular expressions be a better choice? You get all the occurrences of a letter as well as if the letter does not appear at all in the string (the test is in a console application - make sure you use `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace):
EDIT: Included the Hangman class and a simple console call:

```
public class Hangman
{

    public List<string> InvalidLetters { get; private set; }

    private string input;

    public Hangman(string input)
    {
        InvalidLetters = new List<string>();
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void CheckLetter(string letter)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, letter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            InvalidLetters.Add(letter);
            Console.WriteLine("Letter " + letter + " does not appear in the string.");
        }
        else
        {
            MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(input, letter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Console.WriteLine("Letter " + letter + " appears in the following locations:");
            foreach (Match m in coll)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "Stack Overflow";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            Hangman h = new Hangman(input);
            string letter = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(letter))
            {
                h.CheckLetter(letter);
                letter = Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: how can i run a function multiple times, and not just the first run? 

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I edited my answer to include the Hangman class and CheckLetter method, as well as a simple console program. I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.IndexOf:

```
string hangmanWord = "Democracy";
int index = hangmanWord.IndexOf("m"); // 2 (at position 2)
int index = hangmanWord.IndexOf("x"); // -1 (not found)
```

Comment: @RoyWagemakers : what kind of text display are you using ?